# Azure Web App WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE setting does not work

Tags: azure, timezone, azure-web-app-service

In our Windows based Azure Web Apps we had a strange problem that our timezone setting was not working. It was set to `W. Europe Standard Time` but the Web Apps still used UTC for the time. When checking the timezone by using the `tzutil /g` command in the console we got `UTC_dstoff` as a result. We also had Web Apps that functioned correctly, but they had exactly the same setting value and gave `W. Europe Standard Time` as result from the `tzutil /g` command.

Comment: If possible, consider *not* using this setting, and instead modifying your application code to deal with time zones internally. For example, in .NET instead of calling `DateTime.Now`, use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` with `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: Good point. However, refactoring the code or just getting the setting right are two different things. Also, because we have customer instances with different time zones. But refactoring in the future will be on the backlog!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours searching we decided to compare the Hex values of the strings between the functioning Web Apps and the ones that do not have the correct timezone. As it turns out the timezone setting value of the Web Apps with the `UTC_dstoff` timezone had none-breaking spaces instead of normal spaces! So if you ever have this issue, please check the hex values of the spaces you used with for example Visual Studio Code and the hexdumper plugin. Maybe it will save you the 4 hours that it took us to figure this out.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that you had non-breaking spaces between the words in the time zone ID you set in the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` app setting?  If so, how did they get there? Did you copy/paste from somewhere that had them?

Comment: We are not sure how this happened, but copy/paste is the prime suspect here indeed.